# ASK_PASS issue with molecule converge

Tags: ansible, centos, vagrant, molecule

I am using Centos 7 and I have little problem to solve.

I suppose to run molecule converge and to be executed on Vagrant virtual machine.
Problem i encountered was that "no tty present and no askpass program specified".
I have tried to solve this downloading **openssh-askpass.x86_64**.
I run command **ssh-add** and also I set env variable export **SUDO_ASKPASS=/usr/libexec/openssh/gnome-ssh-askpass**
After running molecule converge, it only shows me following result:

```
command: sudo chown 0:0 /tmp/vagrant20220819-16333-fd90np
stdout: 
stderr: [sudo] Passwort for "username": : No such file or directory
sudo: no password was provided
```

Is there any solution i could overcome this issue?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem setting env variable as

```
export SUDO_ASKPASS=/usr/libexec/openssh/gnome-ssh-askpass
```

Because I am doing this in `python3-molecule` is there anyway I can save it permanently?

Thanks again

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).